# How to add javascript variable in the commands

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

Is there any way to add the variable into the jQuery command like this :

```
var id = 10;
var msg = CKEDITOR.instances.contentedit+id.getData();
```

I expect

```
CKEDITOR.instances.contentedit10.getData();
```

from the code above

But it does not work for me and caused the errors as it does not properly add the variable to the command.

Comment: Look at @pointy 's answer below. Should do the trick.

Comment: By googling ["*dynamic property name javascript*"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var msg = CKEDITOR.instances["contentedit" + id].getData();
```

The `[ ]` operator does exactly the same thing as `.`, but it allows any expression instead of just an identifier.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal because it would be an error if it were not.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal no, "contentedit" is part of the name of the property. It has to be a string. The only variable involved is "id".

Comment: A variable, appended to the string "contentedit" to create the full name, thus the quotes.